# How to wire up a logic-level MOSFET to a PWM Signal?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pwm, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to control a 12V Led strip with a logic-level MOSFET transistor ([STP36NF06L](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/ca/9a/86/cf/24/84/4f/34/CD00003405.pdf/files/CD00003405.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003405.pdf)), but I have no idea how I should wire it up.

This:

```
 _______
|       |
|       |
|       |
 ───────
 |  |  |
 |  |  |
 ↑ LED strip GND in
    ↑ 3.3V PWM Signal
       ↑ LED strip GND out
```

Wouldn't work, right?

Sorry if this is a very noobish question, but I have found absolutely no good ressources online explaining how I should set this up.

Answer (score 2):

The basic circuit you need is this.

[image]

Your N Mosfet is switching the load (the LEDs) to ground. R1 limits the initial gate current (gate acts like a capacitor to ground) and R2 discharges the gate ensuring the mosfet is completely off if disconnected from the arduino. The 0V of the battery needs to be connected to the 0V (ground) of the arduino

Comment: If my power supply is an ATX supply, would the ground be common to all black wires? I've followed exactly what you said, And it's not working correctly. Having the mosfet disconnected from the arduino doesn't turn it off.

Comment: Then either you've connected the mosfet the wrong way around - in which case it acts as a diode or its broken. Your connections should be pin 1 - gate, drain - pin 2 (to led negative) and source - pin 3 (ground).